# Cвязанный выпадающий список в Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Как реализовать выпадающий список с значениями из другой таблицы?
Есть 3 таблицы:
Отчет;
Проекты;
Задачи.
В отчет нужно импортировать проекты и задачи к ним

Comment: Вот здесь об это очень подробно: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz8SX0iNPyAIiAmca-nKdrMXjBw2ji89t

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы создать выпадающие списки, необходимо импортировать данные из внешних Таблиц, а после этого настроить [раскрывающийся список в ячейке](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=ru).

Импортировать можно через функцию [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=ru)

```
// В ячейки B1:B10
=IMPORTRANGE("abcd123abcd123"; "Задачи2017!A1:C10")
```

А создавать списки не вручную, а через [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

```
// Устанавливает выпадающий список в ячейку A1 и требует совпадения значения с
// диапазоном B1:B10, дополняя поле выпадающим списком.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1:B10');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь об это очень подробно: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz8SX0iNPyAIiAmca-nKdrMXjBw2ji89t
А именно: здесь рассмотриватся несколько принципов организации связанных выпадающий списков (от создания промежуточного листа с формулами до бесконечных выпадающих списков, где в каждой ячейке уже содержится список вариантов для выпадающего списка).
Под каждым видео есть ссылки на скрипты.
Для тех же, кто не силён в программировании, показано, как воспользоваться готовым скриптом.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)